# copy object with elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to copy an object with some elements?

I want to copy this object, but each `elm` still refers to the same DOM element?

```
var fields = {
    account_id_ : {
        name : Lang.get('HDL_ACCOUNT'),
        width : 60,
        elm : $('<input class="inp" type="text" style="text-align:right" />'),
        value : '',
        focus : true
    },
    name : {
        name : Lang.get('HDL_NAME'),
        width : null,
        elm : $('<input class="inp" type="text" />'),
        value : ''
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean it still refers to the same DOM element. The `elm` variable is assigned a newly created element which is not even yet inserted into the DOM.

Comment: no, but its still somehow added to the DOM.. I want to use multiple instances of this object.. this is a template to some rows I want to add to a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just [loop through](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the jQuery object (and the elements, 1 in this case, that it references.  A very concise method would look like this:

```
var fields2 = $.extend(true, {}, fields);
$.each(fields2, function(n, f) { f.elm = f.elm.clone(); });
```

Now `fields2` has it's own elements, [you can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ctz5z/), compare it [to here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ctz5z/1/) which doesn't run the clone line, and references/re-appends the *same* elements, instead of clones in the first example.

For clarity, a raw javascript version of the clone loop would look [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ctz5z/2/):

```
for(var fieldName in newFields) {
    var field = newFields[fieldName];
    if(field .hasOwnProperty("elm"))
        field.elm = field.elm.clone();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd refer to John Resig's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object). Short answer: use .extend()

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* wanted to include references to DOM elements, you'd have to:

1. Use `$(...).get(0)` so that there's only DOM elements rather than jQuery objects in the tree
2. Do a deep `$.extend()` of the original object
3. Recursively search the copy for any value which is an `instanceof HTMLElement`
4. Convert each such value into a `.clone()` of itself

Something like (untested):

```
var fields = {
    account_id_ : {
        name : Lang.get('HDL_ACCOUNT'),
        width : 60,
        elm : $('<input class="inp" type="text" style="text-align:right" />').get(0),
        value : '',
        focus : true
    },
    ...
};

function cloneDOM(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (Object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var val = obj[key];
            if (val instanceof HTMLElement) {
                obj[key] = $.clone(val);
            } else if (val instanceof Object) {
                cloneDOM(val);
            }
        }
    }
}

var copy = $.extend(true, {}, fields);
cloneDOM(copy);
```